# Invoking an Azure Function from an Azure LogicApp

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

An Azure Function can be invoked from a LogicApp using the default LogicApp connectors or a HTTP POST method.

We are using the default connector provided by LogicApp. The FunctionApp resides in the same region. This was working without any problem. Now, all of a sudden, every call to the function throws the following error.

> The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value.

When using the LA connectors, we do not even have to provide the 'code' parameter value, as it is handled by LogicApps internally.

Is this a known bug and is there a workaround?
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Naren, I'm further investigating this as we have seen more reports involving Logic Apps. I'll update if there is any additional information to share.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Thanks Fabio. I'll mail you more details that might help you.

Comment: Your function app name would be ideal!

Answer (score 0):

Did you renew the key for the Azure Function you're calling? If so, open the logic app and save the workflow again should resolve the issue. (Because Logic Apps designer tracks whether the code behind and disable save if it's not dirty, you may need to change the JSON you're passing to the function, save, revert the change and save again.)

Comment: No, the function keys were not renewed. After starting to see the above mentioned errors, I renewed keys and checked if it solved the issue, but it did not. Then, we ended up redeploying our LogicApp which solved the problem for now. But, it will be very difficult to redeploy or clone(some articles online say this works) every time we face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Naren,

This would happen if the function was re-created, the secret was renewed or revoked, causing the information stored by Logic Apps to become invalid.

Recreating or updating the Azure Function invocation action in logic apps should trigger a synchronization, forcing Logic Apps to fetch the current keys.

You can validate that your current key works by opening the function in the portal and invoking that function directly. When you do, ensure you're making this request using the **default** function key (you'll see that in the Keys panel) as that is what Logic Apps will be using.

Comment: I am getting the same error when I hit the function directly with the **default** key under **Admin Keys (All Functions)**
And no, we did not revoke/renew keys.